# Related taxonomy blocks on taxonomy page

Tags: taxonomy-terms, search

I have a property website with several taxonomies

Area
Post-Code
Station
Size

What I would like is a series on blocks/ views on each taxonomy page which show the realted taxonomies of all properties of a specific taxonomy

For example, if I In Taxonomy Page - Area/Area1 I would like to display a list of related taxonomy terms in a block for post-code, Station and size.

I can create blocks on an individual property which display blocks showing all taxonomy terms for that property., and using the example above I can show a block which shows area on the area taxonomy page or I can show all post-codes, stations, and size .

What I cant do is limit the terms to only show related terms drawn from the current taxonomy

I guess this is similar to a faceted search

Thanks

Comment: This question looks partly the same as your previous question. Please beware of asking twice, edit answer instead. This could be your answer: http://www.metachunk.com/blog/adding-related-content-view-drupal-7

Comment: Hi, yes sorry, it is the same issue I am having, although had refined. It didnt occur to me to amend existing question but will do the the futre.

Comment: Thanks for this link. What this does is give me a related taxonomy for an individual node - or my example a property which I have already achieved. What I am trying to do is show a block on a taxonomy term page - i.e domain.com/area/area1 which shows all related post-codes or izes for the properties which appear in area1 as opposed to the entire lists of properties